# SelectedItemIndex Mismatch when using a CollectionView refresh on a SL ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, combobox, silverlight-5.0

If you have a ComboBox bound to a CollectionView. Issue a REFRESH on that CollectionView and that filters out certain items thus changing the position of your selected item and reducing the size of Collection below the SelectedItemIndex. Then it leaves the combobox in an unusable state. From the sample below

- the button is pushed which sets the selecteditem
- I then issue a refresh on the collectionview
- Visually everything seems great... Because in the Combobox you see 5 as the selected item
- click on the combobox and SL crashes with an annoying error

I traced it down to a part in the ComboBox where upon opening it it passes the SelectedItemIndex to a method SetContentPresenter. But the SelectedItemIndex is wrong so it crashes :-(

Here's my View Model code

```
 public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataObject> ItemSource;
    public ICollectionView CollectionView { get; set; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ItemSource = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>();

        var source = new CollectionViewSource();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            ItemSource.Add(new DataObject(){ Id = i, Description = i.ToString()});
        }

        Filters = new List<string>();
        source.Source = ItemSource;
        CollectionView = source.View;

        CollectionView.Filter = (x) =>
            {
                if (Filters.Count == 0)
                    return true;

                return  Filters.Contains((x as DataObject).Description);
            };

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    internal void ButtonPushed()
    {
        SelectedObject = ItemSource.First(x => x.Description == "5");
        Filters.Add("1");            
        Filters.Add("5");
        CollectionView.Refresh();
    }

    public List<string> Filters
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    DataObject _SelectedObject;
    public DataObject SelectedObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedObject;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedObject != value)
            {
                _SelectedObject = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedObject"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Model Code

```
public class DataObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }
}
```

View Code

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>
    <Button Content="Run Test" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = DataContext as MainPageViewModel;


        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>vm.ButtonPushed());
    }
}
```

I've ended up working around this in my project by not doing two way binding on the combobox selecteditem but instead using the CurrentItem on the CollectionView as a conduit of communication between my VM and the combobox. This way I can null the current item before issuing a refresh and then I can set the Current Item which keeps the Combobox in a consistent state.

In the application this combobox is part of a cascading combobox implementation. So selecting one item in another combobox causes another combobox to filter down but the item already selected might still be a viable option.

Comment: Kudos, it looks like you have found a bug in the Combobox control. Perhaps even in the Selector base class. I wonder if it also effects ListBox and other derivatives. - Was there a question, or is this just an observation?

Comment: Cool I logged a bug on connect. Since it's SL I don't think that matters at all :-).  I guess I was just vetting that I wasn't doing something fundamentally silly and that I'm right in thinking this should work and not crash SL. I couldn't find anyone else with this issue so I felt like there was something simple I was missing.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780938/selecteditemindex-mismatch-when-using-a-collectionview-refresh-on-a-silverlight-5-combobox

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems that you have  set the bound SelectedItem to a specific data object, and then removed that object from the list.  I don't see what else the ComboBox is going to do other than throw an error as it's state has been invalided.  So I don't think this is a ComboBox issue.

What I would do is after Refreshing is see if the SelectedObject is still a valid object. If it is not, then remove it from the list.  Then you will not get the error.

```
 internal void ButtonPushed() {
        SelectedObject = ItemSource.First(x => x.Description == "5");
        Filters.Add("1");
        Filters.Add("5");
        CollectionView.Refresh();
        ValidateSelectedDataObject();
    }

    public void ValidateSelectedDataObject() {
        DataObject currentSelectedItem = this.SelectedObject;
        this.SelectedObject = null;
        foreach (DataObject item in CollectionView) {

            if (item.Id == currentSelectedItem.Id) {
                this.SelectedObject = currentSelectedItem;
            }
        }

    }
```

Greg